# Windows 7 command prompt closing pretty much straight away after opening

Tags: windows-7, command-line

Been double clicking both 'cmd' and 'Command Prompt' on start menu, running on administrator on both, use the Run tool and used /k (cmd /k) on a Windows 7 machine, but everytime I'm opening it the windows closes in a second or so, not giving me enough time to write barely a word. Trying to make a repair usb which requires me to write a number of commands. So any suggestions on what's the problems? Thanks for your time.

Comment: You should run the command from runas box `sfc /scannow`.

Answer (score 0):

Try entering `command.com` into run (Windows Key + R)

Comment: 'Windows cannot find command.com' :(

Comment: Do you have an antivirus application that may be using "application control" on cmd.exe?

Comment: The only anti-virus program I have is Malwarebytes (and Clamwin, but that's just checking through files for sure)... sorry, how do I check?

Comment: It's "command.exe", not .com

Comment: Didn't work, neither did cmd.exe or cmd.com. Damn, I've spent more than an hour trying to find out the problem to no avail.

Comment: My apologies, command.com is XP only. perhaps a download of freedos would help?

Comment: Re: freedos: if it were me, I'd try and figure out why this is happening instead of a work-around. Sounds fishy.

Comment: Thanks for commenting, check my comment on the other answer to see what I did. I really don't know what happened, but it's all fixed and done... for now

Comment: @acme64 Actually, command.com isn't XP only. I have it on my Win 7 PC and school laptop.

Answer (score 0):

Open windows explorer and right click your C: drive while holding the shift key down.  The menu should include the option "Open command window here".  Select that, and you should be in a command prompt window on the root of C:.

Comment: For me, copying the cmd.exe from the system folder and pasting somewhere else worked... don't know how that worked, but the issues resolved. Thanks for the comment- I'd answer the question myself but theres a time limit :/